# Why does Rhythmbox use a different version number?

Tags: rhythmbox

On Ubuntu 11.10, [rhythmbox](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox) is [2.90.1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/rhythmbox), while it [seems to be based](https://launchpad.net/rhythmbox) on the [0.13](http://projects.gnome.org/rhythmbox/). Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rhythmbox 0.13.3 is older than the current packaged version. Launchpad may be missing release information for the main series or this package is linked to the wrong Rhythmbox series.